# Import ARCGIS web dataset contours into Sketchup

Tags: contour, arcgis-rest-api, sketchup

My local council has online ARCGIS data sources including 1m elevation contours.  I am trying to import these into a sandbox terrain model in sketchup to do some landscape planning.

Conceptually I know what I need to do, and can generate the necessary REST API queries to get the data, but am just not able to string it all together.

The contour dataset is here:

http://gisservices.scc.qld.gov.au/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation

An example bounding box for the query is {17008011.278814,-3090615.13623876,17008111.278814,-3090515.13623876}

I can dump the contours in KMZ, and they look great in google earth, however Sketchup (15.3) is unable to import the KML, it just gives a generic 'Import error' dialog.

Also, looking at the KMZ data it doesn't actually have the elevation data, it's pure 2D contours which Google Earth is just clamping to ground level.

If I do a JSON export of the contours, and include the 'CONTOUR' field in the output dataset then I get lots of contour polylines (and elevations) but then I am stuck trying to get that into Sketchup.

I should be clear, I don't have the ARCGIS software at all, I'm trying to do this purely by scraping the REST API of the online data repository.  This is just a private/hobby project.